# Can you set a different JSON for every users in Locust?

Tags: python, json, load-testing, locust

So I have a scenario for a load test, where each spawning user POST a different JSON (In this case i spawning 100 user)

this is the example JSON for POST, where **SITE_CODE** should be different for every request

```
def generateJson(site): 

try:

 payload = {
                "clockin":  [
                    {
                    "SITE_CODE": generateSiteCode(site),
                    "EMP_NO": "1202-31009",
                    "SEQUENCE": 120,
                    "EMP_NO": "1202-00036",
                    "CLOCKING_STATUS": "40",
                    "CLOCK_IN_TIMESTAMP": "2021-11-16 12:09:24.276",
                    "CLOCK_IN_LONGITUDE": 106.8630792,
                    "CLOCK_IN_LATITUDE": -6.2426467,
                    "CLOCK_IN_PHOTO": f.read(),
                    "CLOCK_OUT_PHOTO": "",
                    "CLOCK_OUT_TIMESTAMP": "2021-11-16 12:11:53.797",
                    "CLOCK_OUT_LONGITUDE": 106.8631024,
                    "CLOCK_OUT_LATITUDE": -6.2426843,
                    "CREATION_USER_ID": "auto_retry",
                    "CREATION_DATETIME": "2021-11-16 12:09:24.276",
                    "CHANGE_USER_ID": "1202-00036",
                    "CHANGE_DATETIME": "2021-11-16 12:11:53.797"
                    }
                ],
```

And here is the example for implementing the task for each users

```
class reqUser1(HttpUser):
wait_time = between(1, 5)

   @task(1)
    def gen_variable(self):
        self.client.get("GenVariable/getVar")
    
   @task(2)
   def post_shift(self):
       self.client.post("/Log", json=generateJson(1), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'})
    
   @task(3)
   def get_item(self):
       self.client.get("/item/getItem")
```

How can i achieve this with Locust ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locust helps you run just about whatever code you give it in a distributed manner. Most typical code that runs in Python should just work when dropped into or called from a Locust task. The code in your `post_shift` task looks like it should work, assuming `generateJson` actually returns the JSON you need. (Your code sample of `generateJson` is incomplete and doesn't show a complete dictionary and doesn't return anything, so as is your code won't work until that is fixed.)

If you fix `generateJson` and it still doesn't result in the behavior you expect, ask a new question of update this one with the details of your code, expected behavior, and actual behavior/any errors you're experiencing.

**EDIT:**

If you want to have all users hit `/Log` but you want Locust to report each request to `/Log` separately, you can use the `name` parameter in your client calls. Locust will [use whatever you put in there](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#grouping-requests) to report the request. Example:

```
   self.client.post("/Log", name="/Log 1", json=generateJson(1), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: first, thank you for your response, so what I'm actually looking for is how to make Locust display the log of each request with the different JSON ? because Locust only showing one request ("/Log")

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want each Locust user to hit a different endpoint than `/Log`? Or do you want each user to hit `/Log` with a different JSON payload but report it in the Locust UI and stats as something else like `/Log 1`, `/Log 2`, etc.?

Comment: very sorry to confuse you, I want each user to hit `/Log` with a different JSON payload and also i can trace log every hit

Comment: Okay, then I edited my answer to add details about how to have all clients hit `/Log` and report each request separately.